# How to pass a variable into a string jquery rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am working on an app where the backend is written in RoR and the front end is written completely in javascript/jquery/ajax. My question is how can I pass a variable into a url for my ajax get request? My code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("button").click(function() {


            $.getJSON('http://www.mydomain.com/recipes/1', function(results) {
            $('#1').val(results.recipe_name)
            $('#2').val(results.author)
            $('#3').val(results.level_of_difficulty)
            $('#4').val(results.instructions)
            $('#5').val(results.activity)


            })

        })

    })
```

Right now, the URL is in the format /recipes/:id and I want the :id to be a variable so that the data will load correctly when I click "show" for different recipes... so something like http://www.mydomain/recipies/recipe_x

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can set the id of the recipe on each link using the data attribute. And then use the id to change the URL.

`<a data-id="1">Recipe 1</a>`

`$("button").click(function(this) {`

`$.getJSON('http://www.mydomain.com/recipes/' + $(this).data("id")`

Comment: It will require jquery.